# why is property null and function undefined

Tags: javascript, checkbox, pdo, onclick, checked

I have checkboxes which follow this format:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="Ancient" name="tag" value="Ancient" checked="checked" 
onclick="calc();"> Ancient<br>
```

---

Without `window.onload =` at the start of `function Calc()` I get this for each checkbox I click on:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'checked' of null
>       at calc

---

With `window.onload =` I get the same error but I don’t click on a checkbox, it is there straight away, and refers to the first instance which is this:

```
if (document.getElementById('Ancient,Commemorative').checked){   
  $(".Ancient,Commemorative").show();
}else {
  $(".Ancient,Commemorative").hide();
}
```

The error doesn't occur when I select the other checkboxes like it did previously without `window.onload`.

I didn’t know if it was because there are two tags for this result and the comma is causing a problem?

When including `window.onload =` I also get this for each checkbox I click on:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: calc is not defined
>       at HTMLInputElement.onclick

This is my code:

```
<script>
window.onload =  function calc(){  
    <?php
    foreach ($coins as $coin){
    ?>

        if (document.getElementById('<?php echo $coin->tags ?>').checked){   
          $(".<?php echo $coin->tags ?>").show();
        }else {
          $(".<?php echo $coin->tags ?>").hide();
        }

    <?php   
    }
    ?>  
};
</script>
```

Please can someone explain how I deal with this issue?

I added window.onload initially thinking javascript code is executing before the DOM is ready. Maybe that was right, because I don't get that for all of the results right now, only the first one, which happens to have two coin tags.

Comment: `window.onload =  function calc(){` - that doesn't create a function called calc - that's a named function expression

Comment: `document.getElementById('Ancient,Commemorative')` returns `null`, it is invalid ID selector..

Comment: calc() is a function that is executed via a click event, right - so, the last code snippet, remove `windows.onload =` and the rest should remain and you should be golden (once you figure out the previous comments solution)

Comment: Also if you have jQuery, USE jQuery

Comment: `$(".<?php echo $coin->tags ?>").toggle($('#<?php echo $coin->tags ?>').is(":checked"));` assuming unique IDs . I think you are mixing class and ID here but do not know since you did not post RENDERED HTML instead of PHP

Comment: Thank you everyone, that's really helpful. Much appreciated! Will post again after I have tried to do what is suggested, hopefully with the solution :)

Comment: mplungjan I have ID's on the input which are the same name as the classes I have assigned to a div. EG <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 <?php echo $coin->tags ?>"> And  there is a checkbox for each $coin->tags  class with corresponding ID.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use a class
2. Use jQuery since you have it

My guess without seeing your HTML

---

```
<input type="checkbox" id="Ancient" name="tag" value="Ancient" checked="checked" class="cointag"> Ancient<br>

$(function() { // on page load
  $(".cointag").on("click",function() {
     $("."+this.id).toggle(this.checked);
  });
});
```

OR assuming you want to show a combination:

Work in progress: https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/u0fnsj43/

```
function showCoins() {
  var clsses = $(".cointag:checked").map(function() {
    return this.id;
  }).get();
  $(".coins").hide();
  if (clsses.length > 0) {
    console.log("."+clsses.join(",."))
    $("." + clsses.join(",.")).show();
  }  

}

$(function() { // on page load
  $(".cointag").on("click", showCoins);
  showCoins(); // in case some are already checked at load
});
```